# xfs - command limit not found

Tags: centos6, xfs

I'd like to set xfs quota on my CentOS 6 server, so I installed `xfsprogs` package. However it says `command limit not found` as shown below.

```
[root@myserver ~]# xfs_quota

xfs_quota> print
Filesystem          Pathname
/vol1               /dev/sda1 (uquota, gquota)
/vol2               /dev/sdb1 (uquota, gquota)

xfs_quota> help limit
command limit not found

xfs_quota> ?
df [-bir] [-hn] [-f file] -- show free and used counts for blocks and inodes
help [command] -- help for one or all commands
print -- list known mount points and projects
quit -- exit the program
quota [-bir] [-gpu] [-hnNv] [-f file] [id|name]... -- show usage and limits

Use 'help commandname' for extended help.
```

Although I execute the command as `root`, administratior commands are not available.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour, and why?

Comment: The `limit` command should be the way to set quota, but I cannot use it so far because it's missing. At least, `help limit` should output the extended help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just the help is lacking the documentation for limit? Did you try something like `xfs_quota -x -c "limit -u bsoft=100m bhard=120m someuser"` already?

Comment: Thank you, Janne. The `-x` option was what I was missing.